# Convert simultaneously to a SHA512 hash

Tags: python, django, hash, django-views, sha

I have this app that generate ramdom strings since alphanumeric&punctuation characters per click. this is my view:

```
import string, random
from hashlib import sha512

def get_random_string(size):    
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def draegg_view(request):
    size = 40
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = genSysForm(initial={'Key': get_random_string(size)})
    else:
        form = get_random_string(size)
    return render_to_response('synopticup/monodra.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My app works perfectly but I want to make a simultaneous SHA512 hash conversion of each random string generated of my app. I wanna see the two results (a field with the random string and other with it respective hash. I was trying in many ways but i can't do it.

I sincerely thank you for your help in advance

What should I change on my view for achieve this objective?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string, random
from hashlib import sha512

def get_random_string(size):    
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def draegg_view(request):
    size = 40
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = get_random_string(size)
        hash = sha512(text).hexdigest()
        form = genSysForm(initial={'Key':text, 'Hash': hash })
    else:
        form = genSysForm()
    return render_to_response('synopticup/monodra.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Assuming the screenshot is a currently working form and you only need to fill in the values.